# How can I insert lines to data using Linux commands based on conditions?

Tags: shell, awk, cat

I have a data file like this:

```
5000 1
6000 1
7000 2
9000 5
10000 5
11000 6
12000 8
14000 9
15000 10
...
```

Data is printed in every 1000 numbers of the first column, but some are missing. In the above example, data from 1000 to 4000, and 8000, and 13000 are missing.

I wish to insert new data lines to missing lines of this data, which contains 0 in the second column. So, the result should look like:

```
1000 0
2000 0
3000 0
4000 0
5000 1
6000 1
7000 2
8000 0
9000 5
10000 5
11000 6
12000 8
13000 0
14000 9
15000 10
...
```

All the way to the end of the file.

Can I do this using some Linux commands like awk and/or cat? Or should I need to write a shell script using if loop?

Comment: You'd use awk for that. No shell loop needed (or even desirable - see [why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/169716/why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could you please try following, written and tested with shown samples in GNU `awk`.

```
awk '
{
  max=(max>$1?max:$1)
  arr[$1]=$2
}
END{
  for(i=1000;i<=max;i+=1000){
    print i, arr[i]+0
  }
}
' Input_file
```

OR create an `awk` variable named `diffStart` and give value there in this case its `1000` and change values there whenever you want to change it.

```
awk -v diffStart="1000" '
{
  max=(max>$1?max:$1)
  arr[$1]=$2
}
END{
  for(i=diffStart;i<=max;i+=diffStart){
    print i, arr[i]+0
  }
}
'  Input_file
```

Output will be as follows.

```
1000 0
2000 0
3000 0
4000 0
5000 1
6000 1
7000 2
8000 0
9000 5
10000 5
11000 6
12000 8
13000 0
14000 9
15000 10
```

Comment: Thank you so much. What if I wish to insert new lines up to the specific number of lines? Let's say, if I wish to insert new lines all the way to the line number 2000 (first column value would be 2000000 in this case), and second columkn to be 0, what should I need to change?

Comment: @exsonic01, I am sorry, I didn't get it, could you please explain it more clearly please.

Comment: Sounds like the start of a [chameleon question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/43478/361691) to me.

Comment: If I wish to insert new data all the way to, let's say, 2000th line (up to the first column value of 2000000) which part shouold I need to change?

Comment: @EdMorton I didn't mean that, I just forget to include that section in the original question, just too late to add to my question now...

Comment: @exsonic01, I am sorry but as Ed sir mentioned in above comment also, queries outside of base question is not encouraged on SO. IMHO you could open a new question for same so that future users will not be confused.

Answer (score 3):

```
$ awk -v step='1000' '
    {
        for (i=prev+step; i<$1; i+=step) {
            print prev+=step, 0
        }
        print
        prev=$1
    }
' file
1000 0
2000 0
3000 0
4000 0
5000 1
6000 1
7000 2
8000 0
9000 5
10000 5
11000 6
12000 8
13000 0
14000 9
15000 10
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$ awk '{while((p+=1000)<$1) print p,0}1' file

1000 0
2000 0
3000 0
4000 0
5000 1
6000 1
7000 2
8000 0
9000 5
10000 5
11000 6
12000 8
13000 0
14000 9
15000 10
```